# subclassing MainWindow with UIWindow but NSSet *touches = 0?

Tags: uiwindow

I am subclassing MainWindow with UIWindow and in that using
hit test method:

```
-(UIView *)hitTestCGPoint)point withEventUIEvent *)event {

    UIView *hitView = [super hitTestoint withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self)
        return [[self subviews] lastObject];
    else if([hitView isDescendantOfView:myView])
    {
        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
```

for (UITouch *touch in touches)
{

if ([touches count] >= 2) {
                // prevent this
                NSLog(@"Count =2");
                return [[self subviews] lastObject];
            }
}
        }
        return hitView;
    }

But I am getting touches as zero object.
I debugged and checked event is always having 0 object.
But responder is having details of the events .
why is like that and how should I get the tap count ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override -sendEvent: instead. The docs state the following about -sendEvent::

> Dispatches events sent to the receiver
>   by the UIApplication object to its
>   views.

Comment: In -sendEvent, you can forward the events but can not be prevented.
I have that already in my class.
It just forwards the the events but if I want to filter it wont.

Comment: If you need to filter some events, call super conditionally. For example, if you want to suppress dispatching an event, just don't call super. Apple's implementation basically just does a hit test and sends -touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled:withEvent: to a subview.

That said, you have to be very careful filtering the events to avoid breaking the dispatching machinery. Can you provide more details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to filter the events in - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//filter events for my custom View(WebView)
 //stop double tap on webview.
Even thought I can figure out in hit test which view is getting tapped.
}

but Events are not getting filtered 
But it seems that (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event already dispatches the events to webview.
Then I thought I should try in hit test but as I told in hit test I am getting events as zero.